Генерация уникального значения для каждой итерации теста для параметризованного класса
Есть класс с тестами; он запускается с фикстурой с параметризацией
@pytest.fixture(scope='class', params=[
    (config.ADMIN_GPM_LOGIN, config.PASSWORD),
    (config.MANAGER_GPM_LOGIN, config.PASSWORD)
])
def client(request):
    login, password = request.param
    client_instance = ScenariosClient(login=login, password=password)
    return client_instance

Я пытаюсь генерировать уникальное значение в тесте с помощью библиотеки faker, но оно генерируется лишь один раз для класса.
Пробовал генерировать с помощью отдельной фикстуры:
@pytest.fixture(scope='function')
def unique__name():
    return fake.name() + " " + fake.email()

При этом, мне нужно, чтобы тест-функция запустилась два раза в соответствии с количеством параметров в фикстуре, так что отдельная параметризация с названиями в тестах мне не подходит.
Пример класса:
class TestScenarioCreateDraft:
    def test_scenario_create_endless_draft_without_description_(self, client):
        config = {
            "name": #тут вставляем генерируемое значение,
            "startedAt": "2019-10-12T07:20:50+03:00",
            "timezone": "Europe/Moscow",
            "isEndless": True,
            "isDebugEnabled": False,
            "disallowProfileReprocessing": False,
        }
        post_scenario_draft = client.create_scenario_draft(
            config_scenario=config
        )


Тут просится hypothesis, но я не настолько хорошо его знаю, чтобы скрестить его с faker. Вот есть модуль hypothesis-faker, но он архивирован, и хз насколько работоспособен, я не проверял.
